# questions about creating a measure newhiresYTD

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

hello i have a problem if you can help me i would appreciate it. i have the test table, with the column year(int), month(int), date_antg, NIF,
I need to create a measure in powerbi that when filtering by month makes a count of how many people were hired from month 4 to the month I filtered. how can I do it?

thanks

I need to create a measure in powerbi that when filtering by month makes a count of how many people were hired from month 4 to the month I filtered. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The DAX for this would be something like this:

```
HiredBetweenMonths = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Test'),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Test'),
        'Test'[Month] >= 4 && 'Test'[Month] <= MAX('Test'[Month])
    )
)
```

This measure, when added to a visual along with a filter for the "Month" column, will dynamically count the number of people hired between month 4 and the selected month in your filter.